# How come ping and browser resolve same domain to different IPs (while waiting for propagation)?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Often I buy an expired domain, and then transfer it from some random registrar to my registrar, and then I change the DNS servers to those of my hosting provider.

(I'm simplifying, I don't buy anything, the company I work for does).

Obviously, after doing that, I need to wait for DNS to propagate, and at the same time I configure stuff on our server. For some of that stuff, I need to wait for the DNS propagation to be complete before I do anything; for other stuff I can begin setting things up and then wait for the DNS propagation to be complete in order for those things to work.

By "configuring stuff" I mean setting up virtual hosts with some websites, or setting up redirects to some other preexisting domain with preexisting content.

During this time I often check to see if propagation is finished (at least where I am), by typing the domain into my browser. It's no huge surprise that sometimes I "hit" my server (meaning the domain name gets resolved to my server's IP) even if it's only been few minutes since the DNS change, and later it goes back to resolving to the old server, because propagation has only started and I guess sometimes I hit one DNS server and sometimes I hit some other one.

However what puzzles me is that often I observe this, consistently for a long period (i.e. several minutes):

- if I type the domain into the browser or launch a wget command from the command line, it resolves to the old domain
- if I do a ping it resolves to the new one.

And not alternating randomly, but sistematically like that for several minutes.

And my question is: how on earth can the two things not be consistent?

I would assume that, whether I'm doing an https request to the domain using a browser or wget, whether I'm trying to connect to it with an FTP client, whether I'm running a ping command from a terminal, ... WHATEVER I do that attempts to reach a given domain from a given machine (through a given network interface), the process of resolving the domain to an IP address should follow the exact same route every time, managed by the OS, and the result can change over time (as propagation progresses) but should not be different depending on the application trying to access the domain. I could understand it being completely random (hitting different DNS servers in my area), but not one application getting systematically one resut and another getting the other.

Any idea?

Comment: Someone please answer this.. This is a huge  problem and very annoying.